# apply along axis using arrays as indicies

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, vectorization

I am trying to do this function in-place without a loop:

```
for i in xrange(2):
    trend[i] = np.convolve(dat[i,0], aW3[:,i], 'same').sum()
```

My best attempt is as follows:

```
trend[:2] = np.apply_along_axis(
    func1d=lambda x: np.convolve(x, aW3[:,i], 'same').sum(),
    axis=1,
    arr=dat[:2,0])
```

but I can't figure out how to correctly index `aW3[:,i]` through `func1d`

#### Constants Used

```
aW3 = np.array( [[ 0.259,  0.407],
                 [ 0.37 ,  0.407],
                 [ 0.259,  0.185],
                 [ 0.111,  0.   ]])
dat = np.array([0.02360784,  0.0227628 ,  0.0386366 ,  0.03338596,  0.03141621, 0.03430469])
dat = dat.reshape(dat.shape[0], 1) # in columns
```

Comment: It's hard to know what you're going for since the first loop doesn't really make sense... if you print out `dat[i,0]` you'll see that it's just a single scalar so your convolution is just a multiplication.

Comment: Yeah I simplified a more complicated calculation. I kept the function because I wanted to emphasise that it's not just a multiplication and I want a generalised function solution

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense on the specific point of your question, making your question unclear.  My guess is that `scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve1d` might do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, that might simplify my actual code. I am interested in the theoretical solution to the above for learning'a sake though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trend = np.fromiter((np.convolve(dat[i,0], aW3[:,i], 'same').sum() for i in xrange(2)), float)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can just use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) for a `vectorized` solution, like so -

```
trend = np.einsum('i,ji->i',dat[0:aW3.shape[1],0],aW3)
```

Or with [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
trend = (dat[0:aW3.shape[1],0]*aW3).sum(0)
```

Comment: I'm not sure the second will work with a function instead of the multiplication you use. I love the first function incorporating Einstein notation though

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane Did the first approach with `einsum` work? If it did, then the second approach must work too, as functionally it's the same as the fist one.